# What does "body > *" mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to understand the CSS effects that jQTouch implements. http://www.jqtouch.com/

It has some CSS definitions that contain syntax like `body > *`

```
body > * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0) scale(1);
    min-height: 420px !important;
}
body.fullscreen > * {
    min-height: 460px !important;
}
body.fullscreen.black-translucent > * {
    min-height: 480px !important;
}
body.landscape > * {
    min-height: 320px;
}
body > .current {
    display: block !important;
}
```

I have searched around for some time, but can't find any hint. Could someone explain it to me?

Does it imply animation?

Comment: granted that it should not be CW, @Tor why *wasted* ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`body > *` means "any direct child of the body tag", e.g. consider the following scenario

```
<body>
    <h1>This will be affected by body > *</h1>
    <div>
        This also
        <p>This will not be affected, because it is not a direct child</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a question, but why would inside a `<div>` still be affected by `body > *`, but `<p>` not?

Comment: The `<div>` in this example is a direct child of `<body>` and therefore affected, anything deeper nested is not affected.

Answer (score 11):

The `>` means that only the following `*` (anything), which is the *IMMEDIATE* child of the `body` will be affected.

So `body > *` basically means every immediate child of the body tag. `body *` means *all* tags inside the body tag, no matter the level.

Answer (score 4):

The > character is a match indicator and the * is the match being indicated.

So

```
body > *
```

means to match any child of Body.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a wildcard selector and simply matches all elements, so `body > *` will match all direct children of the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

`body > *` means "any element that is a direct child of the `body` element."

Compare this to `body *`, which means "any element that is a descendant of the `body` element." So this would also match the `<a>` element in `<body><p><a>...</a></p></body>`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`*` refers to all elements, and `>` means immediate child elements, so `body > *` means all immediate child elements of the body.

It's probably a hack of some kind to refer to a particular browser, though I'm not familiar with it.