# What does this CSS rule mean? > *

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to understand the following CSS (perhaps not pure CSS):

```
.A {
    padding: 0
    .B {
        > * {
           boxShadow: '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)'
        }
    }
}
```

The part I don't understand is:
`> * {}`

I'm familiar with `>` as a child combinator placed between two selectors, but here it isn't between two selectors - so what does this rule mean?

I believe `*` selects everything inside whatever component `>` is selecting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183875/what-does-body-mean-in-css

Comment: _perhaps not pure CSS_: You are correct, this is SASS as you also identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you placed here is [SCSS(SASS)](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

This will generate the following CSS:

```
.A {
    padding: 0;
}
.A .B > * {
    boxShadow: '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)';
}
```

And the meaning of `.B > * {}` is this will select any element that is immediate children of .B Class.

Comment: SASS is written with two styles. The Style that is placed here is Called SCSS. SASS/SCSS a nice and efficient way to write and manage CSS.

Answer (score 4):

This will effectively compile to:

```
.A .B > * { ...
```

So basically, any element that is a direct child of `.A .B`

Answer (score 2):

It means - every direct child to ".B". It will select the h1 and p tags in this example, but not the span:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>
      <span>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes descendant selectors go a bit overboard, selecting more than hoped. At times only the direct children of a parent element need to be selected, not every instance of the element nested deeply inside of an ancestor. In this event the direct child selector may be used by placing a greater than sign, >, between the parent element and child element within the selector.

For example, article > p is a direct child selector only identifying p elements that fall directly within an article element. Any p element placed outside of an article element, or nested inside of another element other than the article element, will not be selected.

Below, the paragraph on line 3 is the only direct child of its parent article, thus selected.

**CSS:**

```
article > p {...}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>...</p>
<article>
  <p>This paragraph will be selected</p>
  <div>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</article>
```